# Is $G/H$ cyclic when $G=S_5 \times \mathbb{Z}$ and $H=A_5 \times 97\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I think it is not because $G$ is non-abelian (because $S_5$ is not) and therefore the quotient cannot be abelian. And then since it is not abelian, it couldn't have been cyclic to begin with.

Comment: No, the quotient can be abelian. Consider $D_6/<s>\cong Z/3Z$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct a map $\varphi: G\rightarrow Z_2\times Z_{97}$ by sending $(a,b)$ to (parity of $a$ ($0$ if even, $1$ if odd), $b$ mod $97$).

It's easy to check $\varphi$ is a homomorphism and $\ker(\varphi)=H$, by first isomorphism theorem $G/H\cong Z_2\times Z_{97}\cong Z_{194}$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 1):

A quotient of a non-abelian group can be abelian. For instance, $G/G$ is always abelian, and even cyclic, for any group $G$. So the argument you give can not be used. Instead, try to compute the quotient $G/H$. You can do that in various ways. For instance, do you think you can just compute $S_5/A_5$ and $\mathbb Z / \mathbb Z_{97}$, and take their product? is $S_5/A_5$ abelian? Alternatively, you can use the isomorphism theorem, once you formulated an idea on what the quotient should be, use it.